# Configure spring cloud config server to use vault as backend

Tags: config, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-vault-config

The documentation [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_environment_repository) shows that, the config server can be configured to use vault as its backend, by simply setting the property below, in `application.properties`

```
spring.profiles.active=vault
```

Even after doing so, when a Embedded config server starts up, it expects a Git repository to be configured as below:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=repo_url
```

It fails with the below exception, without the git repo property set.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 
'environmentRepository' defined in class         org.springframework.cloud.config.
server.config.
EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration$GitRepositoryConfiguration: 
Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
You need to configure a uri for the git repository
```

I am not sure how to get the config server look up the vault server running at `localhost:8200`.

Comment: It's not released yet and is only available in snapshots.

Comment: @spencergibb - Thanks for your response. I tried using the snapshots available in the maven repo. How do you suggest integrating vault with spring applications for storing secured database credentials?

Comment: Have you read this article for more context? https://spring.io/blog/2016/06/24/managing-secrets-with-vault

Answer (score 0):

When use vault as backend you have to add the vault server info in config server (application.yml)

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        vault:
          port: 8200
          host: 127.0.01
```

Then add the authentication token in config client (bootstrap.yml)

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      token: myroot
```

Ref: 
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html#vault-backend
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html#_vault